# Filtering two different Collections in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following two collections as input and I need to find Resources who doesn't to belong the activities in input.

Input1:

```
<ActivityAssignments xmlns="http://www.example.org">
   <Activitys>
      <ActivityId>ActivityId13</ActivityId>
      <ActivityName>ActivityName14</ActivityName>
   </Activitys>
   <Activitys>
      <ActivityId>ActivityId15</ActivityId>
      <ActivityName>ActivityName16</ActivityName>
   </Activitys>
  </ActivityAssignments>
```

Input2:

```
<ResourceAssignments xmlns="http://www.example.org">
   <Resources>
      <ActivityId>ActivityId20</ActivityId>
      <ResourceName>ResourceName20</ResourceName>
   </Resources>
   <Resources>
      <ActivityId>ActivityId13</ActivityId>
      <ResourceName>ResourceName22</ResourceName>
   </Resources>
<Resources>
      <ActivityId>ActivityId15</ActivityId>
      <ResourceName>ResourceName23</ResourceName>
   </Resources>
  </ResourceAssignments>
```

I need the ouput as below using XSLT 1.0

```
<FinalResults>
<FinalResource>
<ActivityId>ActivityId20</ActivityId>
<ResourceName>ResourceName20</ResourceName>
</FinalResource>
</FinalResults>
```

Please help me to achieve the above result.

I tried the following xslt but it has duplicate values.

```
<xsl:param name="outputVariable.payload"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$outputVariable.payload/ns0:ResourceAssignments/ns0:Resources">
      <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:ActivityAssignments/ns0:Activitys">
        <xsl:if test="$outputVariable.payload/ns0:ResourceAssignments/ns0:Resources/ns0:ActivityId != /ns0:ActivityAssignments/ns0:Activitys/ns0:ActivityId">
          <ns0:FinalAssignments>
            <ns0:Final>
              <ns0:ActivityId>
                <xsl:value-of select="$outputVariable.payload/ns0:ResourceAssignments/ns0:Resources/ns0:ActivityId"/>
              </ns0:ActivityId>
              <ns0:ResourceName>
                <xsl:value-of select="$outputVariable.payload/ns0:ResourceAssignments/ns0:Resources/ns0:ResourceName"/>
              </ns0:ResourceName>
            </ns0:Final>
          </ns0:FinalAssignments>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Thanks

Santosh Hemashekar

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I edited my question with the XSL I tried. I am still a beginner in XSL

Answer (score 0):

Ok, presuming that `$outputVariable.payload` has the XML specified in your second sample, here is a "push-style" approach to this problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org"
                exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">

  <xsl:param name="outputVariable.payload" select="document('SOResA.xml')"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" priority="-3">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <FinalResults>
      <xsl:variable name="takenActivityIds" select="ns0:Activitys/ns0:ActivityId" />
      <xsl:variable name="allResources" 
                select="$outputVariable.payload/*/ns0:Resources" />
      <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="$allResources[not(ns0:ActivityId = $takenActivityIds)]" />
    </FinalResults>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Resources">
    <FinalResource>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:ActivityId | ns0:ResourceName" />
    </FinalResource>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Now I have. Looks like keys don't work quite how I thought they did.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "collections" in XSLT 1.0 and there can be only one "input" (i.e. the file being processed by the XSLT stylesheet). Assuming you are passing the path to the second file (Input2.xml) as a parameter, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="externalDocument" select="'file2.xml'" />

<xsl:template match="/ns0:ActivityAssignments">
    <xsl:variable name="actIDs" select="ns0:Activitys/ns0:ActivityId" />
    <FinalResults>
        <xsl:for-each select="document($externalDocument)/ns0:ResourceAssignments/ns0:Resources[not(ns0:ActivityId=$actIDs)]" >
            <FinalResource>
                <ActivityId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:ActivityId"/>
                </ActivityId>
                <ResourceName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:ResourceName"/>               
                </ResourceName>
            </FinalResource>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </FinalResults>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FinalResults>
   <FinalResource>
      <ActivityId>ActivityId20</ActivityId>
      <ResourceName>ResourceName20</ResourceName>
   </FinalResource>
</FinalResults>
```